# Mediasoup requires SSL even in localhost?

Tags: express, webrtc, mediasoup

I'm developing a project using mediasoup, in all examples server is running under
ssl, even in localhost is this required? I guess certificate is for remote peers can use media resourses, but browsers allow consume media resourses in http://localhost

Comment: You can sniff plain text passwords being sent across loopback without encryption. So yes, encryption is still required for localhost access.

Comment: Thanks @Bib Can you post answer to mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sniff plain text passwords being sent across loopback without encryption. So yes, encryption is still required for localhost access.